# Check if something is an instance of ArrayCollection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, instanceof

Usually you it is possible to check whether a variable is an instance of a class by using:

```
$foo instanceof bar
```

But in the case of ArrayObjects (belonging to Symfony 2), this does not seem to work

`get_class($foo)` returns `'Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection'`

yet

```
$foo instanceof ArrayCollection
```

returns `false`

`is_array($foo)` returns `false` and `$is_object($foo)` returns `true`

but I would like to do a specific check on this type

Comment: Are you using this with a form ?

Comment: Yes Im using this in a form builder

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To perform introspection of an object under a namespace, the class still needs to be included using the `use` directive.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

if ($foo instanceof ArrayCollection) {

}
```

or

```
if ($foo instanceof \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection) {

}
```

Regarding your attempt to determine the objects use as an array with `is_array($foo)`.

The function will only work on the `array` type.  However to check if it can be used as an array, you can use:

```
/*
 * If you need to access elements of the array by index or association
 */
if (is_array($foo) || $foo instanceof \ArrayAccess) {

}

/*
 * If you intend to loop over the array
 */
if (is_array($foo) || $foo instanceof \Traversable) {

}

/*
 * For both of the above to access by index and iterate
 */
if (is_array($foo) || ($foo instanceof \ArrayAccess && $foo instanceof \Traversable)) {

}
```

The `ArrayCollection` class implements both of these interfaces.